# Flag summary sort by active disputed helpful declined etc

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, declined-flags, disputed-flags, flag-history

I can see my flag summary page at https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1391924 as shown below.

> [image]

On the right side you will get number of flags categorised by helpful, declined, waiting for review etc. But no links are provided to see these type of flags.

Also these category of flags can be arranged in tabs as shown in user page https://stackoverflow.com/users/1391924/chandrayya-g-k (like summary, questions, answers etc)

Comment: Broght here by Jon Clements: Please also provide a filtering for "aged away" flags to be able to find them fast for propbably reflag them. Jon Clements mentioned that no filtered list for those exists at the moment, see my question at: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308454/where-do-i-find-a-list-of-posts-where-my-flags-aged-away?noredirect=1#comment260983_308454

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been completed in the latest build (thank to Oded). The sidebar stats on the flag history page will now allow filtering for any of the categories available in your history.