# How can I review a flag?

Tags: support, flag-history, flag-ban

I tried to flag a post but I got this message:

> Your last flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post!

This message is linked to my Flagged Posts list, but I don't see any option to review my last flag ( neither do I see any review flag option on my last declined flagged post).

I thought I was not able to flag a new question because of the message:

> Your last flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post!

I thought I needed to do some special action to validate the `review`.

But I missed the little grey text 'enter at least 10 characters', that's because I was under 10 characters the 'Flag question' button was grey. Stupid me.

Comment: [Ugh, not again.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226159/how-to-review-my-flags) To [*review*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/review) something is to simply look at it and understand it. That's all. It isn't an "option" or a link or a button, despite what Stack Exchange might have you believe.

Comment: @BoltClock So I just have to wait days/weeks after I read the reason why the last flag was declined before being allowed to create a new flag ?

Comment: @BoltClock so how would you define review audit then?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227045/make-reviewing-declined-flags-less-painful

Comment: @Donaudampfschifffreizeitfahrt: It's however Stack Exchange chooses to define it. There is no general definition of "review audit" because that term is unique to Stack Exchange (AFAIK).

Answer (score 8):

You go to your [Flag summary page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/3845124)

> [image]

where you can see all your flags and the status. Look for the ones that got declined and the message that goes with it.

> [image]

<s>There is no real UI to *review* your flags or find the last one that was flagged and caused the message to appear</s>. The reviewing of your own flags has become easier with the implementation of [filtering in your flag history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254784/flag-summary-sort-by-active-disputed-helpful-declined-etc). You might find [Flag banned after getting a helpful flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253496/flag-banned-after-getting-a-helpful-flag) also interesting to read.

The actual review activity is considered to be a self-learning exercise. You revisit the post and re-evaluate if you would have chosen the same flag again. Your own review should result in better muscle memory to flag similar posts differently given the declined outcome of your earlier flag.

When you're unsure or disagree you can [search on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=declined+flag) to find out what the community consensus is or [ask a new question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) on meta.
Explain that you want guidance on preventing declined flags with regard to your interpretation of how to use flags for specific posts.

Do notice that the message stays there until one of your (new) flags gets approved. When seeing that message you are not yet flag-banned but are close to a ban. Be careful and search on meta or [meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405) for how to flag correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you missed the first message (as indicated in rene's answer) and actually can't flag any more then, unless you have other "active" flags, the only thing you can do is to wait until you can flag again.

If you have other "active" flags then if enough of these are marked as "helpful" you'll be able to flag again sooner rather than later.

However, I should point out that if you are getting this message then you're not doing a very good job of flagging and perhaps you should take a break and think about what you are flagging and what flag reason you are choosing. It might be that you are correctly identifying poor content but that it really doesn't need to be brought to the moderator's attention. If a down-vote, comment or edit would solve the problem (or at least indicate to the OP what the problem is) then you can do all of these yourself. The moderators have enough to do in dealing with stuff that regular users can't handle, you adding to that list with stuff that you *can* handle isn't going to go down well.

Comment: I flagged 1 time only, and yes now I understand that it was a poor idea. I should have edited the post instead.

Comment: @Pierre - you shouldn't have been blocked from flagging because of one poor flag. That might be an issue.

Comment: @Pierre I saw your edit that the flag button was disabled because you didn't type enough characters. [The message you saw was correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405); if a user's first flag is declined, we want them to look in their profile to find out why so that they can better learn how flagging works. If you run into any other issues that seem wrong, though, do let us know.

Comment: @Laura 3 moderators for my silly mistake, I don't deserve so much attention ;) thanks for your time, you moderators do a great job on stackoverflow

Comment: @Laura: The only thing I find somewhat confusing about the message is that it still shows after you already reviewed the flag. One time I got a flag declined, I went to my flag list, and studied the post and my flag in detail. Then I wanted to flag another post later, and I got the message that I should review my last flag. Telling me to do something I already did is... irritating.